# How to reload a CollectionView after receiving network data in Swift?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, uicollectionview

I'm using an async http request to fetch JSON data. When the `CollectionView` loads for the first time, my array is still empty (and consequently `numberOfItemsInSection`).
When I get the response, I'll try to reload on the main thread, but not sure how to reload the `CollectionView` properly.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            //reload CollectionView here            
        })
```

Comment: I'd appreciate it if any downvoters of my comment could explain what part of my question they find objectionable. Where does the disagreement lie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reload a collection view just simply call `reloadData` on the main thread:

> func reloadData()
>
> Call this method to reload all of the items in the collection view. This causes the collection view to discard any currently visible items and redisplay them.

Example:

```
collectionview.reloadData()
```

Calling reload data will cause all of the collection view's delegate methods to be fired again which would call `numberOfItemsInSection:`.

Comment: The question isn’t clear on what precisely the “async method to fetch JSON data” is, but wrapping it in a main thread dispatch is necessary if the calling code is not on the main thread.

Comment: Edited to make it clear. But I mean: async call to fetch JSON from a service.